# Kendo datasource sync offline changes after app restart

Tags: kendo-ui, phonegap, offline-caching, kendo-datasource

I'm developing a mobile Phonegap app with Kendo UI, making use of it's Offline DataSource features.

Unfortunately, I've stumbled across a scenario where offline changes are not being sent to the remote server when the datasource is back online. It goes like this:

1. The datasource reads from the remote server and places the data into localStorage
2. The device goes offline and a change is made to a data item (the item is flagged with `__state__: 'update'` in localStorage)
3. The app is closed whilst the device is still offline
4. The device goes online whilst the app is still closed
5. The app is started again and `datasource.online(true)` is called
6. The changes are NOT synced to the remote server, despite the offline data having the appropriate `__state__` property

It was my understanding that calling `datasource.online(true)` would immediately sync any offline changes. Any ideas why this is not happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found that I first need to set the datasource offline, then read the offline data from localStorage, before switching back to online mode:

`datasource.online(false);
datasource.read();
datasource.online(true);`

offline changes are then synched woth the remote server.